# Get connected HDMI device's HDMI version in android app

Tags: android, chromecast, hdmi

How can I get the connected HDMI device's version in android app? There is nothing in DisplayInfo that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to give you that; that information is not even known to the sender app.